# How to replace every specific character to another in a string C?

Tags: c, string, loops, for-loop

I program in C. I'm supposed to create a program which identifies what is the most common character in a string and what's the second most common character.

I'm not sure why, but it's not working. the program should put into an integer the location of it. Not a pointer but if the most common is `str1[i]` then it will put into an integer the value of `i`. And so in the second most common. If it is `str1[j]` than it should put into an integer the value of `j`. then, it's supposed to replace the most commons with the second most common. The replacement function works, there's probably a problem in the loops although I can't figure out what is it.

Here's what I have (assume all of the integers and strings are declared in the beginning):

```
void stringReplace(char str1[], char ch1, char ch2);

int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char ch1, ch2;
    int i, j, p, n, len, counter1, counter2, first, second, times;
    printf("Please enter the string - maximum = 100 characters:\n");
    printf("User input: ");
    gets(str1);
    len = strlen(str1);
    for(i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        counter1 = 0;
        for(j = 0 ; j < len ; j++)
        {
            if(str1[i] == str1[j])
            {
                counter1++;
            }
            if(counter1 > counter2)
            {
                first = i;
            }
        }
        counter2 = counter1;
    } //character which shows up most - found.

counter2 = 0;

    for(p = 0 ; p < len ; p++)
    {
        for(n = 0 ; n < len ; n++)
        {
            if(str1[p] == str1[n])
            {
                counter1++;
            }
            if(counter1 < first && counter1 > counter2)
            {
                second = p;
            }
        }
        counter2 = counter1;
    }

    ch1 = str1[first];
    ch2 = str1[second];
    stringReplace(str1, ch1, ch2);
    puts(str1);
    return 0;
}

void stringReplace(char str1[], char ch1, char ch2)
{
    int i, j, len;
    len = strlen(str1);
    for(i = 0 ; i <= len ; i++)
    {
        if(str1[i] == ch1)
        {
            str1[i] = ch2;
        }
    }
}
```

Where's the problem ?

Comment: if `len` is the actual length of the string, then one problem is that your `for` loops should have `< len` not `<= len`. Otherwise you're going through `len+1` characters and processing the null terminator (if there is one).

Comment: done but still not working :(
I'll edit to the whole program so you would understand :P

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, that's just "one problem". There may be others. Also, you didn't fix all the cases. ;)

Comment: what doesn't work? where is the program going wrong? where is the program working properly?

Comment: The replacement and such are well. 
But if I type for example "I love you more" (supposed to come out I leve yeu mere") then it'll come out "I lov you mor".

Comment: you should initialize counter2 to some value before using it.

Comment: Not the case... It's initializing to 'counter1' as soon as I use it (it is initialized in the first loop. Used in the second).

Comment: Now after changing <= to < it just types "I love you more" when I input "I love you more"...

Comment: `if(counter1 > counter2)
            {
                first = i;
            }` counter1 and counter2(prev counter1) There is no sense to `first` since this is increased or decreased(In the result of the last), respectively.

Comment: also You need to ignore  space?

Comment: Read your own code! You compare counter2 and counter1 in the inner loop, before initializing it

Comment: The What happens when (same  the number of count) by first candidate is more than one? Only whether one is adopted?

Comment: manuell, reseted. didn't help. and BLUEPIXY I didn't understand your question. Please help me people :(

Comment: +1 for me having fun coding

Comment: You seems to never accept answers. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to find the n max numbers in a string, being n=2, right?
I did a little working example for you. The code differs slightly from yours but it works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str[] = "Algorithms Are Funnnn!\0";
    int i=0;
    int offset=33;
    int ocurrs[94] = {0}; //considering from 33 to 126 (valid chars - ASCII Table [0-127]).
    int max[2]={0};

    while(str[i]) 
        ocurrs[str[i++]-offset]++;

    for(i=0; i<94; i++)
        if(ocurrs[i]>ocurrs[max[1]]){
           max[0] = max[1]; 
           max[1] = i;
        }
        else if(ocurrs[i]>ocurrs[max[0]]) 
           max[0]=i;

    printf("chars '%c'(%d times) and '%c'(%d times) occurred most.\n",
        offset+max[1], ocurrs[max[1]], offset+max[0], ocurrs[max[0]]);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, try to stay away from gets as it's totally unsafe.
If you want to grab 100 chars max, use this instead:

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
```

Regards.

Comment: Are you talking about max[2]?

Answer (score 0):

Can't resist to find an answer with some *loops*, without the populate occurence technique.

Very fun to code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {

    char szInput[] = "ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY WALK INTO MORDOR!";
    int len = strlen( szInput );

    int MaxCountSoFar_1 = 0;
    int MaxIndexSoFar_1 = -1;
    int MaxCountSoFar_2 = 0;
    int MaxIndexSoFar_2 = -1;
    int i, j, CountThatOne;

    for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        if ( szInput[ i ] == ' ' ) continue;
        // count that char
        CountThatOne = 1;
        // don't start from 0, they are already "counted"
        for ( j = i + 1; j < len; ++j ) {
            if ( szInput[ i ] == szInput[ j ] ) ++CountThatOne;
        }
        if ( CountThatOne > MaxCountSoFar_1 ) {
            // push old first max to new second max
            MaxCountSoFar_2 = MaxCountSoFar_1;
            MaxIndexSoFar_2 = MaxIndexSoFar_1;
            // new first max
            MaxCountSoFar_1 = CountThatOne;
            MaxIndexSoFar_1 = i;
        } else {
            // catch second one, but not if equal to first
            if ( CountThatOne > MaxCountSoFar_2 && szInput[ i ] != szInput[ MaxIndexSoFar_1 ] ) {
                MaxCountSoFar_2 = CountThatOne;
                MaxIndexSoFar_2 = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( MaxIndexSoFar_1 >= 0 ) {
        printf( "Most seen char is %c, first seen at index %d\n", szInput[ MaxIndexSoFar_1 ], MaxIndexSoFar_1 );
        if ( MaxIndexSoFar_2 >= 0 ) {
            printf( "Second Most seen char is %c, first seen at index %d\n", szInput[ MaxIndexSoFar_2 ], MaxIndexSoFar_2 );
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```